# having trouble downloading geckodriver

Tags: firefox, extract

I have tried to downlaod geckodriver and I have been running into issues. I have downloaded it from the github/com/mozilla/geckodriver section for win64. I extracted it and put it into put my designated folder in my C drive inside the scripts section. However, in my ubuntu terminal, when I try to check to make sure that it was downloaded properly by typing geckodriver --verion it states that geckodriver cannot be found but can be installed with sudo apt install firefox-geckodriver. I then type that command and it gives me three error messages. It states, "Failed to fetch [http://security.ubuntu.com/pool/main/f/firefox"](http://security.ubuntu.com/pool/main/f/firefox%22) and so forth. Then it states "unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?" The other message stayes failed ot fetch [http://security.ubuntu/pool/universe/firefox/firefox-geckdriver"](http://security.ubuntu/pool/universe/firefox/firefox-geckdriver%22) and so forth. I am not sure what is going on and would like some help. I made a folder and then put a virtualenv inside for it and then i went to the scripts section and that it where I believe I extraced geckodriver to.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. There is no C Drive in Ubuntu, and why do you downoad win64 version?? Do you use WSL maybe ? Also, I think the "Failed to fetch" - issue is unrelated to the rest, and you should copy the real and complete error messages, otherwise the answer will be that `security.ubuntu` is not a possible domain name.

Comment: Sorry I should clarify. I know there is no c drive in unutu but when you got o /mint/c/Users/ you will be able to access the same files that you put into the c drive for windows.; I am using WSL. So to retrieve files in my C drive for windows I have to go to /mnt/c/users to access those same files. For example, if I am using pandas in VSC to read an excel file and I am using WSL in order to find the excel file I have to sue the path /mnt/C/Users. But if I am just using windows I can put C/Users/ and so forth.

Comment: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.come/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/firefox/firefix-geckodriver_93.0+build1-0ubuntu.20.04.1_amd64.dev 404 not found

Comment: It stays E in red so I am assunig that is the error message. The other messages state: "Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?" the last one states "failed to fetch http://security.ubunut.com/ubuntu/pool/univerise/f/firefox/firefox-geckodriver_93.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb 404 Not found."

Comment: `firefox-geckodriver` https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=firefox-geckodriver&searchon=names .............. *Your* links are invalid / have typo's. (All four links). .... The package is at **universe**, please see mirror example  https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/amd64/firefox-geckodriver/download